# minSdkVersion=8 runs into Froyo, but not in HoneyComb or ICS

Tags: android

i've created an apk to run in all android devices after API 8. Tested in the emulator for all APIs and it worked fine. However, after putting the apk on Google Play, some users of HoneyComb and ICS complained that the APK was not running. Here is the link for my apk in Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=designtec.android.rss

And here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
package="designtec.android.rss" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/iatec" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Main" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".StartMain" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainCalc" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".Info" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".NaturezaDoSom" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".CaracteristicasDaAudicaoHumana" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".PropagacaoAoArLivre" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".PropagacaoAoArLivre_PerdaPresDist" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".PropagacaoAoArLivre_VelTemp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".NaturezaDoSom_FreqPer" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".NaturezaDoSom_FreqVelSom" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".NaturezaDoSom_NumDobVol" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".NaturezaDoSom_NumOitDuasFreq" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".NaturezaDoSom_SisMasMola" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".CaracteristicasDaAudicaoHumana_NumDobVol" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".CaracteristicasDaAudicaoHumana_NumOitDuasFreq" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".CaracteristicasDaAudicaoHumana_QuantoVarTempo" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".ODecibel_Bel" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".ODecibel_dBm" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".ODecibel_dBSPL" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".ODecibel_dBu" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".ODecibel_Decibel" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".ODecibel_PVR" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".ODecibel" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".ODecibel_DecibelTensaoEletrica" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".Pagina" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
</application></manifest>
```

Comment: "not running" is not sufficient information for identifying the issue. Does it crash? Did you get a crash report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont have acces to a device with ICS or honeyComb, you can create a AVD (emulator) to try it out.. Check your logcat for error report.. I think this is the best i can help you with the info above.